# React optimum useEffects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently working on a single page dapp for lucky bunny farm, it all works and will be released soon. But i'm wondering if maybe i've engineered it entirely wrong because i have put most of the business logic within a collection of useEffects (6). Because i dont have any other pages on the site i've not created hooks as i would in other situations because there's no benefit from a writing code point of view.

It seems to me that having 6 useEffects working off the state variables i've set might be a little much, is there a performance gain from reducing them or doing something else? I have created components for the various on page assets and those internally have their own state and useEffect hooks too. What's the danger in a "large" number of these hooks and at what point should i consider optimising for performance.

Or am i over thinking this and actually this is quite normal and i should only worry when i have say 20 hooks all doing their own thing.

Additionally, i tend to use state for single variables instead of objects, is there a performance gain from using a single state with an object.

So to use an example i have the following states:

```
dappActionStarted
dappActionCompleted
dappActionError
```

Would it be more efficient to have something like:

```
{
   started
   completed
   error
}
```

And then do a single useEffect for that object as opposed to the three i would need to manage 3 seperate state vars.

Comment: If you are using react 18 they have added automatic batching (about your second question): https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-automatic-batching

Comment: no not yet, still on 17 havent looked at upgrading yet as it'll no doubt have a bunch of breaking changes. but i'm reading up on the things now.